# Scala - Combine Substrings from a Vector using Reduce

Tags: function, scala, collections

Hi I am trying to figure out a way to take the first 2 letters of each name in a vector and produce a String of all the first 2 letters from the list combined.

```
val names: Vector[String] = Vector("June", "Jane", "James", "Iain", "Kate", 
"Beth", "George", "Jack", "Ben", "Bob", "Neil", "Simon")    
val try1 = names.reduceLeft((str1, str2) => str1.substring(0, 2) +
str2.substring(0, 2))
val try2 = names.reduceLeft((str1, str2) => str1 + str2.substring(0, 2))

//try1: String = JuSi - With both substringed
//try2: String = JuneJaJaIaKaBeGeJaBeBoNeSi with only str2 substring
```

The comments show the respective results.
I presume from my results that changing str1 stops iteration from occuring (or atleast stops it from working as intended).
What should I do here for the desired result? Obviously I could remove 'n' and 'e' from the final result, but the fact that I would need to do this suggests I am using the wrong operation for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indeed cannot use `reduce` for what you do, since it uses the first element as aggregator. Use `foldLeft`:

```
names.foldLeft("")((str1, str2) => str1 + str2.substring(0, 2))
```

To help you understand what is going on, let's look at a simple example where:

```
val names = Vector("June", "Jane", "James")
```

Using `reduceLeft`, you get:

```
"June" + "Jane".substring(0, 2) + "James".substring(0, 2)
```

Using `foldLeft`, you get:

```
"" + "June".substring(0, 2) + "James".substring(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to do this with map and mkString. For example:

```
val result = names.map(a => a.substring(0, 2)).mkString
```

The _ wildcard can be used and substring() replaced with take:

```
val result = names.map(_.take(2)).mkString
```